# gulp-glify breaks js code for two recent packages - what are my alternatives?

Tags: javascript, bower, gulp-uglify

I have a large project with many included packages.  Two of the recent updates:

```
angular-timezone-selector@1.6.0 
jwt-decode@2.0.3
```

break the minimized js code. And 'gulp serve' works fine when uglify is not invoked. Using:

```
 .pipe(plugins.uglify({mangle: false, compress:false}))
```

doesn't keep the js from being broken.

The breakage is different for the two packages:

1) angular-timezone-selector.js must have a ';' added at the end of the

```
angular.module('angular-timezone-selector'....)
.factory(...)
.factory(...)
.directive(...)
```

NOTE: however that this ';' is not needed by js.

2) awt-decode breaks something else... but what exactly is not clear.

SO I am looking for an alternative uglify or an alternative minifier. For now I have to patch any bower update with the two projects under version control which is very ugly.

If you have encountered these issues, your help would be greatly appreciated.  I could keep these two packages from being minimized, but I would rather solve the underlying issue since in the past few years I have encountered broken minimization a number of times and it is always difficult to determine which package is breaking and why.

Answer (score 0):

wich uglifier you use? I load 
https://github.com/terinjokes/gulp-uglify

from npm and it allways work fine.

Comment: Yes - the gulp-uglify is the one that I use and it works FINE for all the other packages.  It is only an issue with the two specific packages listed above.  AND it might be dependent on the order of the packages, etc... I haven't checked that.  But there may be an easy way to use a different mimizer or uglifier.  I am looking for a more robust solution.

Comment: I have opened an issue on gulp-uglify also.